# How can I stop a background-process started from bash after the next command finished?

Tags: bash, shell, shutdown, background-process

How could I manage, that the morbo-server called here as a background-process will be shutdown/killed automatically if I close the Firefox-window or if I stop this script in some way?

```
#!/bin/bash

morbo Mojolicious_Lite.pl &

firefox -new-window http://localhost:3000/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, let's solve this one.

```
#!/bin/bash
morbo Mojolicious_Lite.pl & P=$!
trap "kill $P" INT # maybe you want EXIT here too?
firefox -new-window http://localhost:3000/
wait
```

This one should work... When firefox exits the shell will wait for remaining jobs (morbo) which then can be interrupted by Ctrl-C - in which case the trap kills them.

You can test it visually (i.e. seeing what gets executed) with

```
bash -x run.sh
```

Assuming your script is called run.sh ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `$_` variable is  the PID of your last background job. Use it to kill your process. To catch errors/signals use `trap` (man bash has an example).

Comment: How could I catch the closing of the firefox-window?

Comment: @Fritschy: yes! you're right. To the orig. poster: If there is already a firefox window on the screen, it gets complicated, you cannot do it in all cases. What if your user opens a new tab and then closes the original tab? Even if you could find out when the window closes, it would be too late Suppose you can catch the tab closing (which you can't, but anyway). What if the user closes the tab and then does "undo close last tab"? What about "duplicate tab"? In short, rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1):

In bash $_ is the last argument to the previous command. To kill a background job you'll have to use job numbers (or PID). An example of using job number:

```
[15:29:29 ~]$ gvim &
[2] 28509
[15:29:31 ~]$ kill %2
[15:29:39 ~]$
[2]+  Terminated              gvim
[15:29:42 ~]$
```

[2] is the job number and is shown when you launch the background process.

Comment: How could I catch the closing of the firefox-window?